# Get reference to (Mock)ResourceResolverFactory

Tags: osgi, sling, sling-models

I have a Sling model class containing a reference to a service of mine:

```
@OSGiService
PlanService planService;
```

This service has a reference to ResourceResolverFactory, to get a ResourceResolver with the "admin user":

```
@Reference
private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;
```

I'm writing a unit test to test adaptTo on my model class. I'm trying to inject the reference to PlanService like this:

```
@Rule
public final OsgiContext osgiContext = new OsgiContext();

osgiContext.registerInjectActivateService(new PlanServiceImpl());
```

But I don't know how to inject the reference to the ResourceResolverFactory.

I've tried like this:

```
osgiContext.registerInjectActivateService(new MockResourceResolverFactory());
```

But I get this error:

```
org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.NoScrMetadataException: No OSGi SCR metadata found in classpath at OSGI-INF/org.apache.sling.testing.resourceresolver.MockResourceResolverFactory.xml
```

I couldn't find in the documentation and among all the mocking options available how to inject this service and get the reference automatically. Any help would be very helpful, thank you!

EDIT:
Thanks to Jérémie's answer, the ResourceResolverFactory is injected in the PlanService. However, I'm now facing this issue:

```
[main] WARN org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory - Required properties [c.r.o.c.s.j.PlanService c.r.o.c.m.Plan.planService] on model class class c.r.o.c.m.Plan were not able to be injected.
```

I've tried to use the same line than for the ResourceResolverFactory:

```
osgiContext.registerService(PlanService.class, new PlanServiceImpl());
```

And also to add

```
MockModelAdapterFactory mockModelAdapterFactory = new MockModelAdapterFactory();
     mockModelAdapterFactory.addModelsForPackage("c.r.o.c.m");

osgiContext.registerService(ModelAdapterFactory.class, mockModelAdapterFactory);
```

But it's still the same problem...

EDIT 2: registering it with SlingContext instead of OsgiContext fixed the issue:

```
@Rule
public final SlingContext slingContext = new SlingContext(ResourceResolverType.RESOURCERESOLVER_MOCK);

@Mock
PlanService planServiceMock;

slingContext.registerService(PlanService.class, planServiceMock);
```

Comment: above solution not working in my case, I am getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
osgiContext.registerService(ResourceResolverFactory.class, new MockResourceResolverFactory());
```

The Javadoc of the `OsgiContext` is [here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.testing.osgi-mock/1.6.0/org/apache/sling/testing/mock/osgi/context/OsgiContextImpl.html#registerService-java.lang.Class-T-)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I edited my question because the second reference (in the model) is not injected. Just if by any chance you would have any tips on what I'm doing wrong. But in any case, I will mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, than I used the guide on https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/osgi-mock.html and I made in the following way. Now it works for me:

```
    BundleContext bundleContext = MockOsgi.newBundleContext();
    //register the service
    bundleContext.registerService(OtherService.class.getName(), new OtherService(), null);
    // get service instance
    ServiceReference ref = bundleContext.getServiceReference(OtherService.class.getName());
    OtherService service = (OtherService)bundleContext.getService(ref);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try cleaning and building your project before you test.

For example,

```
gradlew clean build test
```